# How to remove AddressBook book-like interface or enable debug menu?

Tags: macos, contacts, ui

I wish to get rid of the Lion 10.7.5 AddressBook book-like interface a.k.a. leather appearance a.k.a. skeuomorphic design.

Usually this kind of setting can be change from the debug menu.

However `$ defaults write com.apple.AddressBook ABShowDebugMenu -bool true` does not enable the debug menu in AddressBook.

How to enable this debug menu or make addresbook look like 10.6 Addressbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [osxdaily.com post](http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/16/remove-leather-appearance-from-address-book-ical-easily-with-lion-tweaks/) let me to [LionTweaks utility](http://tweaksapp.com/download_lion.html) to do the job. It seems that LionTweaks launches installers that are originally from [macnix.blogspot.nl](http://macnix.blogspot.nl/2011/07/change-mac-os-x-107-lion-ical-and.html).

LionTweaks version 2.0.2 on 10.7.5 give me back the old aluminium/grey/10.6 look for iCal although the top text has a yellow/brownish shade.

Address book becomes grey but still feels like the 10.7 address**book**.